# Do I need UK visa to enter London from Cork, Ireland?

Tags: visas, uk, iranian-citizens, common-travel-area

I am an Iranian citizen who is going to Cork, Ireland for a short visit with an Irish tourist visa. Can I go to London with this visa or do I need UK visa?

Answer (score 3):

So the [Guidance - Common travel area (CTA)](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/common-travel-area-cta/common-travel-area-cta) claims

> certain persons ... who enter the United Kingdom through the Republic of Ireland do require leave to enter.
>
> 2. persons requiring visas;

The exact same text can also be found in the [Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/370896/20141106_immigration_rules_part_1.pdf) paragraph 15. Be warned that the [old rules](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/262652/section2__1_.pdf) seems not to include this therefore you might get friendly advice which is outdated now! The law has changed in 2014.